# Yii 2 не парсится модель при отправке через AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Есть такая модель:

```
namespace app\models;    
use yii\base\Model;    
class AjaxTest extends Model
{
    public $text;    
}
```

Есть действие контроллера, которое формирунет страницу с формой:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index',['model'=> new AjaxTest()]);
}
```

Сама форма:

```
<?php
$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form',
    'action' => '/man/test',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'validationUrl' => 'my-validation-url'
]);
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textInput(); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php $form->end(); ?>
```

Есть отправка формы через AJAX на JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').on('beforeSubmit', function () {
        var $yiiform = $(this);
        // отправляем данные на сервер
        $.ajax({
                type: $yiiform.attr('method'),
                url: $yiiform.attr('action'),
                data: $yiiform.serializeArray()
            }
        )
        .done(function(data) {
           if(data.success) {
              // данные сохранены
            } else {
              // сервер вернул ошибку и не сохранил наши данные
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
             // не удалось выполнить запрос к серверу
        })

        return false; // отменяем отправку данных формы
    })
})
```

Есть действие контроллера, которое принимает данные формы по AJAX^

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new AjaxTest();
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {            
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();            
        if ($model->load($data)) {
            return [
                "data" => $model->text,
                "error" => null
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                "data" => null,
                "error" => "error1"
            ];
        }
    }else{
        return [
            "data" => null,
            "error" => "error2"
        ];
    }
}
```

Данные приходят:

> { "_csrf":"BvO32H7Bg1m8swSJQgMvbUQt3SMMXHMmJzgp8sSjXlN1nYaJOLnNKfr0Xrp0dxwjMFrofGspP3VWYHqErus9IA==",
>       "AjaxTest":{"text":"123"} }

**Вопрос**

Если всё отправляется и приходит, то почему `$model->text` всегда `null` (хотя должен быть "123")? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Может все же отправка по умолчанию Get? А если отладчик поставить на строку `$data = Yii::$app->request->post();` и посмотреть что там есть?

Comment: В `$data = Yii::$app->request->post();` приходит как раз то, что я привёл в вопросе. Так что данные через POST приходят точно.

Comment: И `$model->load($data)` почему-то `true`.

Comment: А рулсы в модели для text прописаны?

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, ларчик просто открывался. Нужно было прописать `rules` для единственного поля модели, чтобы всё заработало.

```
class AjaxTest extends Model
{

    public $text;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [
                [
                    'text'
                ],
                'string'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

*P.S. Спасибо fedornabilkin за подсказку.*